# Where does Linux kernel do process and TCP connections cleanup after process dies?

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel

I am trying to find place in the linux kernel where it does cleanup after process dies. Specifically, I want to see if/how it handles open TCP connections after process is killed with -9 signal. I am pretty sure it closes all connections, but I want to see details, and if there is any chance that connections are not closed properly.

Pointers to linux kernel sources are welcome.

Comment: I'm curious if you fond an answer, and if it happened to be a kernel issue, or a networking issue. Also, updating your question would help others that stumble upon this later on.

Comment: @JimB, If you are interested in our network issue, then no, I don't know what the problem is/was. We added those idle connections check and use so_keepalive now, but there is so much traffic, that it's very hard to do traffic dump and verify if certain packets get lost or not. About that closing, I checked sources that caf mentioned in his answer, and I believe that Linux kernel at least *tries* to close the sockets when process is killed. If it succeeds or not is another question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The meat of process termination is handled by [`exit.c:do_exit()`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.36/kernel/exit.c#L892).  This function calls `exit_files()`, which in turn calls `put_files_struct()`, which calls `close_files()`.

[`close_files()`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.36/kernel/exit.c#L462) loops over all file descriptors the process has open (which includes all sockets), calling `filp_close()` on each one, which calls `fput()` on the `struct file` object.  When the last reference to the `struct file` has been put, `fput()` calls the file object's `.release()` method, which for sockets, is the `sock_close()` function in `net/socket.c`.

Answer (score 7):

I'm pretty sure the socket cleanup is more of a side effect of releasing all the file descriptors after the process dies, and not directly done by the process cleanup.

I'm going to go out on a limb though, and assume you're hitting a common pitfall with network programming. If I am correct in guessing that your problem is that you get an "Address in use" error (EADDRINUSE) when trying to bind to an address after a process is killed, then you are running into the socket's TIME_WAIT.

If this is the case, you can either wait for the timeout, usually 60 seconds, or you can modify the socket to allow immediate reuse like so.

```
int sock, ret, on;
struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

sock = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 ):

/* Enable address reuse */
on = 1;
ret = setsockopt( sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &on, sizeof(on) );
```

[EDIT]

From your comments, It sounds like you are having issues with half-open connections, and don't fully understand how TCP works. TCP has no way of knowing if a client is dead, or just idle. If you `kill -9` a client process, the four-way closing handshake never completes. This shouldn't be leaving open connections on your server though, so you still may need to get a network dump to be sure of what's going on.

I can't say for sure how you should handle this without knowing exactly what you are doing, but you can read about [TCP Keepalive here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/). A couple other options are sending empty or null messages periodically to the client (may require modifying your protocol), or setting hard timers on idle connections (may result in dropped valid connections).

Comment: Thank you... cleanup of file descriptors would indeed lead to closing of connection. Btw, I am running into different problem ;-) Our server sees stale connections from clients that have been killed with -9, and we are trying to find out why. For now solution our is to automatically close idle connections from the server and also to use SO_KEEPALIVE, but we're trying to understand the problem too.

Comment: Then it seems that you are having problems with half-open connections. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for update. I read Tcp keepalive faq just yesterday. We have added dropping of idle connections to the server too. Modifying protocol to send "pings" from server is not an option, but we will combine SO_KEEPALIVE with dropping of idle connections, and that should do for us. What confuses me is that when I am playing with kill -9 locally, kernel tries to close this connection just fine. Btw, clients and servers are both in our control on same network, we are seeing this problem on one deployment only.

Comment: You may need to get a dump of the network traffic to pin this down. Now that I think about it (and with @caf's corroboration), even `kill -9` should let the socket close, and put the server in CLOSE_WAIT, which shouldn't really cause a problem. The half-open state I was describing is usually caused by power, link, or routing issues, where the client simply disappears.

Comment: "In the event of a SIGKILL signal, [...] TCP sockets [...] need to be flushed and go through the TCP shudown process." according to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/386551/15513